# How to set up a real-time computing node/point in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Can Apache IoTDB build a specified computing node? I want to calculate real-time data of wind fields for provinces. For example, I have measuring points A and B. I can create measuring point C and set the calculation formula to be C=A+B , and set this calculation process to be real-time. I want to achieve that there is a measuring point C, which can calculate the sum of A and B in real time. (Real-time means that the timestamp of C can be synchronized with A and B). Are there any relevant functions and documentation in IoTDB to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vision function in Apache IoTDB to achieve this. A view of certain time series is like a virtual time series. Each virtual time series is like a soft link or shortcut, mapping to a time series outside the view function or some calculation logic outside the view function. Therefore, you can set up the calculation logic and then use view function to synchronize this logic in real time.